# TFS and Project portal sync

Tags: portal

Just installed TFS 2008. Created a project with portal site.
When I create a bug in TFS from Visual Studio I'd like to see that bug in the web portal. And the other way around. When I add a task in the web portal I'd like to see that in Visual Studio.

It's as if the web portal is not connected to TFS.
I'm using the MSF for Agile Software Development template.

I just saw Team System Web Access. That's what I want in addition to the other pages Sharepoint portal provides. For example the Wiki page and calendar view.

So one place to see all tasks lists and assign task and see other project related pages. Maybe be able to has the tasks due dates come up on the calendar.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean [Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980951.aspx), or are you entering items in SharePoint elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah I just saw Team System Web Access. Not really I want the task,bugs... list in the Sharepoint portal along with other stuff like Wiki.

Comment: Those aren't connected...the documents are, but not that stuff.  2010 has more of a portal integration in SharePoint, but 2008 TSWA is the method, it was actually made by a third party company and bought by MS, in 2010 it was really tied in all around.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to do this is to create a Reporting Services report against the TFSWarehouse, then embed the report into the project portal.  This would give you a read-only view of the items.